# Pin curve points for sofbody

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, soft-body

I have curve, bezier, and applied softbody to it. Now question I have is, how can I pin one point on curve? I see Goal settings on softbody, and Vertex group option, but there is no vertex group for curve.

Comment: Found solution, setting weights on points does the trick.

Comment: Answer yourself and accept your answer.